# Web scraping with Phantomjs/Selenium (from R), setting element values

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, automated-tests, rselenium

The problem scraping tabular data from http://www.nasdaqomx.com/commodities/market-prices

I can get data, but I can't seem to change/set parametres on the page, and so retrive other data.

These are the id's I can find on the page:

'#marketSelectId, #typesSelectId , #productsSelectId, #dateId,#isTraded, #excelId'

And those i need to change seems to be (selector gadet from Chrome):

'#marketSelectId, #isTraded' (code from the webpage at the end)

Any help as how to change these.

My phantomjs attempt is the following:
    // phantomNasdaqOmx.js

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'NasdaqOmx.html';

page.open('http://www.nasdaqomx.com/commodities/market-prices/history/',
function (status) {

// no luck
//  page.evaluate(function(){
// document.getElementById("#isTraded").value = false;
//  });

// no luck
//  $('.myCheckbox').removeAttr('checked');

// no luck
page.evaluate(function(){
document.getElementById('marketSelectId').value='EUK';

});

var content = page.content;
fs.write(path,content,'w');

phantom.exit();
});
```

My Rselenium attempt

```
require('RSelenium')
library('XML')

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                  , port = 32770L
                  , browserName = "firefox"
)

remDr$open()

site <- "http://www.nasdaqomx.com/commodities/market-prices" # create URL for each page to scrape
remDr$navigate(site) # navigates to webpage
## remDr$findElements(using = 'xpath', value = '//*@id')
remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('marketSelectId').setAttribute('value', 'EUK')")

remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('isTraded').setAttribute('value', '')");
##a <- remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('isTraded').getAttribute('value')")
## remDR$ findElement(By.id("isTraded")).getAttribute("value");
##
##  Throws error
##  remDr$click(buttonId = 'isTraded')

elem <- remDr$findElement(using="id", value="derivatesNordicOutput") # get big table in text string

## elem$highlightElement() # just for interactive use in browser.  not necessary.
elemtxt <- elem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]] # gets us the HTML
elemxml <- htmlTreeParse(elemtxt, useInternalNodes=T) # parse string into HTML tree to allow for querying with XPath
readHTMLTable(elemxml)

head(master)
```

marketSelectId - needed values and script information: 'eno', 'ede', 'euk'

```
//*[(@id = "marketSelectId")]
webpage js code
<label>Market:</label> <select id="marketSelectId">
    <!--optgroup label="Electricity"-->
    <option selected="selected" value="ENO">Electricity Nordic</option>
    <option value="EBE">Electricity Belgium</option>
    <option value="EFR">Electricity France</option>
    <option value="EDE">Electricity Germany</option>
    <option value="EIT">Electricity Italy</option>
    <option value="ENL">Electricity Netherlands</option>
    <option value="EES">Electricity Spain</option>
    <option value="EUK">Electricity UK</option>
    <!--/optgroup-->
    <option value="EUA">Carbon Market</option>
    <option value="ZEE">Natural Gas Belgium</option>        
    <option value="PNO">Natural Gas France</option>
    <option value="GPO">Natural Gas Germany</option>
    <option value="TTF">Natural Gas Netherlands</option>
    <option value="NGUK">Natural Gas UK</option>
    <!--option value="ELEUR">Electricity Certificates</option-->
    <option value="ELSEK">Swedish Electricity Certificate</option>
    <option value="NCFO">Fuel Oil</option>
    <option value="NCDF">Freight - Dry</option>
    <option value="NCTC">Freight - Tankers Clean</option>
    <option value="NCTD">Freight - Tankers Dirty</option>
    <!--option value="COAL">Coal</option-->
    <option value="NCSF">Seafood</option>
    <option value="STEEL">Steel</option>
    <option value="NCIO">Iron Ore</option>
    <option value="RWEU">Renewables</option>
    <option value="COKCOAL">Coking Coal</option>
</select>
```

isTraded - script information and wish to change from checked to 'UNchecked', (do not know the right value for this field, the code seems to check for 'checked' and else, but that does not work

```
//*[(@id = "isTraded")]
webpage js code
        // only those who have oi or volume
    if ( $("#isTraded").is(":checked")) {
        xpath += "[ph/hi/@rv!='' or ph/hi/@tv!='']"; //or ph/hi/@oi!=''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `clickElement` method. You can also use the `selectTag` method to manipulate select menus

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("http://www.nasdaqomx.com/commodities/market-prices")
isTraded <- remDr$findElement("id", "isTraded")
isTraded$clickElement()
waitforupdate(remDr)
marketSelect <- remDr$findElement("id", "marketSelectId")
msSelect <- marketSelect$selectTag()
# select seafood market
seafood <- msSelect$elements[msSelect$text == "Seafood"][[1]]
# switch to seafood market
seafood$clickElement()
waitforupdate(remDr)
elem <- remDr$findElement(using="id", value="derivatesNordicOutput") # get big table in text string

## elem$highlightElement() # just for interactive use in browser.  not necessary.
elemtxt <- elem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]] # gets us the HTML
elemxml <- htmlTreeParse(elemtxt, useInternalNodes=T) # parse string into HTML tree to allow for querying with XPath
readHTMLTable(elemxml)

# function to wait for update to appear
waitforupdate <- function(remDr, maxwait = 30){
  chk <- FALSE
  count <- 0L
  while(!chk && count < maxwait){
    count <- count + 1L
    res <- suppressMessages(
      tryCatch({
        remDr$findElement("css", "#derivatesNordicOutput span[title = 'Last update']")
      },
      error = function(e){e}
      )
    )
    chk <- !inherits(res, "error")
    Sys.sleep(1L)
  }
  if(count >= maxwait){
    stop("table has not updated in alloted time")
  }
}

# UPDATE get german electric prices
gerElec <- msSelect$elements[msSelect$text == "Electricity Germany"][[1]]
gerElec$clickElement()
waitforupdate(remDr)
elem <- remDr$findElement(using="id", value="derivatesNordicOutput") # get big table in text string
elemtxt <- elem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]] # gets us the HTML
elemxml <- htmlTreeParse(elemtxt, useInternalNodes=T) # parse string into HTML tree to allow for querying with XPath
readHTMLTable(elemxml)


# close browser and stop server
remDr$close()
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```

Comment: Thanks @jdharrison, still having a few problems with getting it right. 
The code works, but with a few quirks, the function 'waitforupdate()' do 'lock' sometimes, I do not know if this i a windows issue,
Trying to set the relevant key: i.e:
'seafood <- msSelect$elements[msSelect$text == "Seafood"][[1]]'
Does give me the seafood values, but using the 'Electricity Germany' do not give me those values, instead returning the 'Electricity Nordic', trying with your suggestion but with value:
 'seafood <- msSelect$elements[msSelect$value == "EUK"][[1]]'
But this do not help either.
Thanks

Comment: @Thorvall I can't replicate your issues. I have added code to get german electric prices.

Comment: Have changed my Selenium instance from a Firefox to a Chrome based docker container, and now i does work. 
Can't tell if it's a Firefox issue, or only when run from a docker container on windows.

Thanks.

Comment: @Thorvall interesting I didnt test it on Firefox. It maybe an issue with the version of firefox the docker container is running.